# Vertical scroll view showing Horizontal effect .Why?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my XML i have a relative layout having vertical orientation ,it has some child views.I have added a vertical scroll view for this relative layout.But it shows a horizontal effect.I could not understand the problem can anyone help ,Here is my XML .

```
<VerticalScrollView android:id="@+id/vertical_scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="none"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/popup_element"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f6f5f3"
android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/previewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/your_text_preview"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="80dp"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="50"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_below="@id/previewText"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_text_here"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/fontArea"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textContainer"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fonts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/colorArea"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/fontArea"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/colors"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<CheckedTextView
     android:id="@+id/shadowCheck"
     android:layout_below="@id/colorArea"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:padding="12dp"
     android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
     android:text="@string/shadow"
     android:checked="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/done"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/apply"
    android:layout_below="@+id/shadowCheck"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/previewText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/previewText"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</VerticalScrollView>
```

Comment: You have an horizontalScrollview inside your view, what do you call "horizontal effect"?

Comment: Relative layout doesn't have any orientation tag so it's ignored. Use LinearLayout in it's place.

Comment: i want the whole layot scrollable vertically

Comment: put xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" inside VerticalScrollView , and make height as android:layout_height="match_parent".

Answer (score 0):

try this changes:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vertical_scroll"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/popup_element"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f6f5f3"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/previewText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/your_text_preview"
                android:textSize="40sp"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="80dp"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="50">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/previewText"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/enter_text_here"
                    android:maxLength="50"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/fontArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textContainer"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fonts"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/colorArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/fontArea"
                android:scrollbars="none">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/colors"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
            <CheckedTextView
                android:id="@+id/shadowCheck"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/colorArea"
                android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="@string/shadow"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/done"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/previewText"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/previewText"
                android:layout_below="@+id/shadowCheck"
                android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
                android:text="@string/apply"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```